# Need a basic simple tutorial on Rails with no tests, no scaffolding PLEASE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand models, views, and controllers from a design DRY perspective. How would I create a basic calculator in rails using best practices. Online there is way too much on scaffolding and tests that it just completely confuses the heck outa me. I dont know where to use what variables and how to decide where they go and all. I am a total noob. Please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a custom controller?

Comment: So you want to create a web application which actually is a calculator? And you are trying to figure out how you can create controllers and views etc?

Comment: How about you just don't look at the parts that discuss the tests?! Not that I'd actually recommend that, but still.

Comment: I don't understand a thing about rails. Can someone explain by a simple comprehensive exAmple?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know how to create a custom controller. Use instance variables in the controller and pull data from a model as well as use the variables from model and controller in the view. Can someone please provide a basic comprehensive example?

Comment: I would strongly recommend investing time in going through the freely available [Ruby on Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) It's a well thought-out book aimed at getting newcomers to become familiar with Rails, as well as the associated tools and best practices.

Comment: I went through the boook, and my head is spinning with octothorps, rspec, cucumber, git, bdd, and rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the basics, it's very useful read the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html).
If it is not enough you can view Ruby on Rails screencasts in [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)

Comment: Rails casts has way too much stuff and by no means basic. I need an example please. Can some one write one up?

Comment: The basics are in the rails guides. If you want an example see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project